# Can page-break-inside be applied in <td> of an HTML Table?

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf, suitescript

In my HTML Printout, the description is so long, in a  that the whole row is starting from the next page. I am fine if the  breaks inside, i just want to know how?

I tried page-break-inside but it didnt work. what else i can use to restrict the whole row to move to next line?

Comment: Hello Anis. Could you give an example or an image of the problem, your try, and your expected result?

Comment: Thank You for replying. I am sending you my google drive link (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Nrub_HTmcn7ScGALgUn6corRIqPvNPfQ/view?usp=sharing) If you see the pdf, its breaking the page after the first line and because the description is too long. what i require is the description to be divided half on one page and half on second so that the first page my not look empty. I tried to include page-breaks on <td> <tr> and even the <table> . but nothing worked.